# ERROR: "The containerapp does not exist" in Azure CLI task at DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure, devops, pipeline, azure-container-apps

I have an issue with my Azure DevOps Pipeline which contains two Docker tasks (Docker build and Docker push) and two Azure CLI tasks (Install azure-cli-extension/containerapp and Update containerapp).

The first Azure CLI task installs the CLI extension with the script:

```
az extension add --source https://workerappscliextension.blob.core.windows.net/azure-cli-extension/containerapp-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl -y
```

And with the second I'm attempting to update an existing container app using the following PowerShell script:

```
# automatically install Container Apps CLI extension
az config set extension.use_dynamic_install=yes_without_prompt

# ensure registry is configured in container app
az containerapp registry set `
   --name acuacontainers `
   --resource-group ACUA-Resources `
   --server acuacontainers.azurecr.io `
   --identity system

# update container app
az containerapp update `
   --name acvalidationapi-test `
   --resource-group ACUA-Resources `
   --image acuacontainers.azurecr.io/validationapi:'$(Build.BuildId)'
```

The error message received is: "ERROR: The containerapp 'acvalidationapi-test' does not exist." Here's the relevant output:

```
WARNING: Command group 'config' is experimental and under development. Reference and support levels: https://aka.ms/CLI_refstatus
WARNING: Command group 'containerapp' is in preview and under development. Reference and support levels: https://aka.ms/CLI_refstatus
ERROR: The containerapp 'acuacontainers' does not exist
WARNING: Command group 'containerapp' is in preview and under development. Reference and support levels: https://aka.ms/CLI_refstatus
WARNING: The behavior of this command has been altered by the following extension: containerapp
ERROR: The containerapp 'acvalidationapi-test' does not exist
##[error]Script failed with exit code: 1
```

I see that the image has a new image tag with the same BuildId into the cloud but the existing container app does not have a new revision.

The pipeline was working two weeks ago and without any change, the pipeline suddenly stopped updating the container app.

Here what I tried:

- I verified all the parameters in the commands: container app name, resource group name, and the container registry name.
- I verified the Service connections in the Azure DevOps project settings.

Please give some hints of what could cause this strange and useless error.

Comment: you have 2 errors in fact: `The containerapp 'acuacontainers' does not exist` and `The containerapp 'acvalidationapi-test' does not exist`. So in you pipeline you re aupdating two different container apps ?

Comment: Also can you confirm that the container apps exists in the resource group `ACUA-Resources`?

Comment: @Thomas, `acuacontainers` is the Container registry, and the `acvalidationapi-test` is the Container App. Both services exist in the resource group `ACUA-Resources`. The Pipeline has been working for six months and I'm getting these errors since two weeks.

Comment: according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/containerapp/registry?view=azure-cli-latest#az-containerapp-registry-set) the `--name` parameter should be the container app not the container registry.

Comment: Also `Command group 'containerapp' is in preview and under development` which mean thing can break/change.

Comment: if you run `az containerapp list --resource-group ACUA-Resources` from your pipeline, can you find the acvalidationapi-test container app ?

Comment: The `containerapp` is for the second command `az containerapp registry set` and the `acvalidationapi-test` is for the last command `az containerapp update`. Therefore I have two different errors for the two commands. Regarding the `WARNING: Command group 'containerapp' is in preview and under development.` I'm using the same version `azure-cli-extension/containerapp-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl` and I think this warning should not be the issue. When I run the script `az containerapp list --resource-group ACUA-Resources` it is quite big and I can see the container app in this list.

Comment: `ERROR: The containerapp 'acuacontainers' does not exist` is because you are setting the container registry as the `--name ` parameter. should be `--name acvalidationapi-test`

Comment: I changed the `--name acuacontainers` with `--name acvalidationapi-test` for the command `az containerapp registry set` but I'm getting the following error now: `ERROR: (InvalidParameterValueInContainerTemplate) The following field(s) are either invalid or missing. Field 'template.containers.validationapi-test.image' is invalid with details: 'Invalid value: "***/validationapi:2450": unable to pull image using Managed identity system for registry ***';.`. I think this command is not the main problem. My problem is updating the container app with the last command `az containerapp update`.

Comment: Also I ran the pipeline without the command `az containerapp registry set` and I'm getting the same error: ``ERROR: The containerapp 'acvalidationapi-test' does not exist`. But if I run the command in PowerShell console at the Azure cloud then the container app is successfully updated: `az containerapp update --name acvalidationapi-test --resource-group ACUA-Resources --image acuacontainers.azurecr.io/validationapi:'2450'`. I think the pipeline can not update the container app via the CLI extension but I don't know why.

Comment: your pipeline does not have the required permission. it needs at least contributor role at the container app level but propably also at the resource gorup level. did the permission changed as you said it was working for a while ?

Comment: Yes, the pipelines were working before and no permission changes since then. In DevOps, we have two Service connections (Azure Resource Manager - Service Principal and  Docker Registry - Azure Container Registry). We have corresponding App registrations into Azure. Both app registrations have Contributor roles to Azure's ACUA-Resources resource group. Even I created a new DevOps Service connection and assigned it to the pipeline but I still got the same errors. What other permissions I could be missing?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I have encountered this after moving a container app to a new resource group. It took ~2 hours to resolve *after* the Azure portal told me the move was completed successfully...FYI, in case anyone else runs into this.